# If $A\subseteq B$, then $A\subseteq A\cup B$ and $A\cap B \subseteq A$. ("Set Theory: A First Course" by Daniel W. Cunningham). What is the intention?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading "Set Theory: A First Course" by Daniel W. Cunningham.
There is the following exercise in this book (Exercise 2.1.1 on p.35):

> **1. Theorem**. If $A\subseteq B$, then $A\subseteq A\cup B$ and $A\cap B \subseteq A$.

I think both $A\subseteq A\cup B$ and $A\cap B \subseteq A$ hold even if $A\nsubseteq B$.

Is this erratum?

What is the author's intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that this holds even when $A \nsubseteq B$.

I assume that the author was going for something like

$A \subseteq B$ iff $A \cup B = B$ iff $A \cap B = A$

Comment: Mark Saving, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're right.   The hypothesis that  $A\subseteq B $ is not necessary.

My only guess is that it's a misprint.   The conclusions $A\cup B\subseteq B $ and oh, I don't know,  something like  $A\cap B=A $, would make much more sense.

Comment: Chris Custer, Thank you very much for your answer. Mark Saving answered first, so I chose Mark Saving's answer as the best answer. I am sorry.

Comment: That's ok.  I'll live.